# Visual Studio 2008 javascript sourcecode shift-indents when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting

Why is the javascriptrows in the current block jumping one tab left when I press enter and then back right when I write a semicolon?

It's very annoying. What's the purpose of it?

The same thing happens on paste operations.

Comment: do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: @Matt No, I don't think so. Add-in manager is empty. Telerik MVC stuff is installed and has a menu, but I guess that's not what you were looking for right?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue today and found that you can deactivate this in:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting

I un-ticked "*Format completed line on Enter*" and "*Format on paste*" and since then it's working ok for me. Only downside is that it won't automatically indent a block of code you're pasting within brackets but it looks like that's the price you'll have to pay!